# Can I do tabs.sendMessage to specific tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

For example, I have 3 tabs opened and the third tab is active. Can I "sendMessage" from the background script to the 1st tab(inactive)?

Also, how to do this, ".tabs.update"

I can do ".tabs.update" to the active tab by this,

```
browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
    stat: "check"
}, function (response) {
    browser.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {
        url: response.url
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This sample sends to previously updated tabs every time a tab is updated.

```js
const tabIds = {};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (changeInfo.status === "complete") {
    tabIds[tabId] = "";

    for (const tabId in tabIds) {
      console.log("sendMessage tabId=", tabId);
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(parseInt(tabId, 10), "hoge");
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: It helps. But how can I do it for `(x)nth` tab? for example 1st tab or 3rd tab?

Comment: Please tell me specifically what you are having trouble with.
Just a technical interest?